# PDO Processing verification

Tags: php, pdo

I have a question on using PDO, when you are inserting information into a database. Assume you have to insert a user's age, date of birth, and his/her name, I know these things would have to be in this format

```
$stmt->execute(array(':age' => $age, ':date_of_birth' => $dob, etc, etc));
```

Would you need to process information that the user didn't submit? Say if I collect an IP address, in the original query, can I just put where ip = $ip, or do I need to put it into the same format above?

Also say if I want to submit .$this->userid. (something like that), would I put it inside the array as is, or would I need to modify it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

PDO uses placeholders any data you wish to bind to the SQL query is  sent in a separate packet e.g. using `execute(array(':placeholder' => $val))` or `bindParam` / `bindValue`.

Unless I miss understand the question: you should not plainly insert values into the query as you're defeating the purpose of PDO/MySQLi

Comment: but are placeholders needed for information you are submitting? For example: IP's

Comment: You should use placeholders whenever you're inserting a variable into a query